# How does C# handle passing null delegates to a native function?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Suppose a C library (let's call it `mylib.so`) exposes the following:

```c
typedef void (*EventCallback)(int);

// there would be an additional declspec macro'd in here
// macro'd in here on Windows
void AddEventHandler(EventCallback ec);
```

In C#, I then use `mylib.so` like this:

```cs
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate void EventCallback(int type);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate void AddEventHandlerFn(EventCallback? ec);

// later in some code ...

IntPtr libHandle = NativeLibrary.Load("mylib.so");
var addEventHandler = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<AddEventHandlerFn>(
  NativeLibrary.GetExport(libHandle, "AddEventHandler")
);

addEventHandler(null);
```

When I call `addEventHandler(null)` in C#, do I get `(EventCallback) 0` in the C function? If not, what actually happens?

Comment: Why don’t you test and find out?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what else could be expected. It's a function *pointer* so it stands to reason you would get a `NULL` pointer. Unclear why you are doing dynamic function loading and not just using `extern` and `DllImport`

Comment: @Charlieface the library I'm using requires me to pass its native handle to other libraries. `[DllImport]`ed functions do not give me that flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a small test project, I found that the behaviour I expected (null delegates becoming null function pointers) to be true.